What is the theory of the measure of a line in a plane
I have been taught how to measure the length of a line in a plane, in typical situations encountered in physics; for instance, by integrating $dl = \sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$ along the line, parametrized in some way.
However, I am currently studying elementary measure theory, with $\sigma$-algebras and all that. The basic perspective given is obtaining the Lebesgue measure over $\mathbb R$, or over a plane, etc. The measure on a plane, let's call it $\mu_2$, will be that of areas; that's not what I am looking for here.
I imagine that the length of a line can be defined through measure theory, as a measure $\mu_\text{line}$ on a plane, satisfying the following conditions:

The measure's value will be infinite on any subset of $\mathbb R^2$ that has nonzero area; in other words, if $\mu_2(A) > 0$, then $\mu_\text{line}(A)=+\infty$.
On any subset of a straight line in $\mathbb R^2$, $\mu_\text{line}$ will agree with the corresponding Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$.
$\mu_\text{line}$ will be invariant by translation and rotation.
...

I am not asking here for a complete answer, but just for pointers to such a theory. How is the measure of a line called? The same of course goes for the measure of a surface in $\mathbb R^3$ and so on. One may also want to define the length of a line, or the area of a surface, intrinsically, that is, independently of the embedding of such manifolds in a larger space. I have started studying the theory of differential manifolds, but it doesn't seem that it can encapsulate the issues of measures. Again, I am just asking for pointers.

Have you looked at Hausdorff measures? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure

Carathéodory (before Hausdorff) did this for "arc length" which is what the OP wants.  Hausdorff generalized to non-integer dimension.
